# How to handle the code when onSurfaceChanged method is being called twice

Tags: android, camera

sometimes depending on device, onSurfaceChanged method called more than once, which results in crash of camera preview(I am using camera2).
I have no idea how resolve this problem. Here is a part of my code:

```
@Override
    public synchronized void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    //  if(!(width == mWidth || height == mHeight)) {
            mWidth = width;
            mHeight= height;
            Log.e("ex1", "onSurfaceChanged = " + width + ", height = " + height);

            //generate camera texture------------------------
            setupSurfaceTexture(width, height);
            surfaceIsDestroyed = false;
        //}

    }

private void setupSurfaceTexture(final int width,final int height) {
       System.out.println("setupSurfaceTexture is being called");
        mCameraTexture.init();

        //set up surface texture------------------
        SurfaceTexture oldSurfaceTexture = mSurfaceTexture;
        mSurfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(mCameraTexture.getTextureId());
        mSurfaceTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(this);
        if(oldSurfaceTexture != null) {
            oldSurfaceTexture.release();
        }

        //get the camera orientation and display dimension, open camera------------
        int orientation = mContext.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

        float rotation = 90; 
        if((orientation == 1) && (newApi)) { // TODO: NEED TO BE CHANGED
            isPortrait = true;
            rotation = 0; 
        }
        icam.openCamera(width, height, mSurfaceTexture);
        System.out.println("Is new API: " + newApi);

        if(mContext.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            Matrix.setRotateM(mOrientationM, 0, rotation, 0f, 0f, 1f);
            if(newApi) {
                icam.updateScaling(width, height, isPortrait);
                mRatio[0] = icam.getCameraWidthOrScaleX();
                mRatio[1] = icam.getCameraHeightOrScaleY();
            } else {
                icam.updateScaling(width, height, isPortrait);
                mRatio[0] = icam.getCameraWidthOrScaleX();// * 1.0f/height;
                mRatio[1] = icam.getCameraHeightOrScaleY();// * 1.0f/width;
            }

        } else {
            Matrix.setRotateM(mOrientationM, 0, rotation, 0f, 0f, 1f);
            if(newApi) {
                mRatio[1] = icam.getCameraWidthOrScaleX();
                mRatio[0] = icam.getCameraHeightOrScaleY();
            } else {
                mRatio[1] = icam.getCameraWidthOrScaleX();//*1.0f/height;
                mRatio[0] = icam.getCameraHeightOrScaleY();//*1.0f/width;
            }
        }
        Log.d("Rotation Portrait", mRatio[0] + "-----" + mRatio[1]);

        //start render-----
        requestRender();
        surfaceSetuped = true;
}
```

Comment: the simplest thing you can do is introduce a flag variable , that prevents the function from getting executed if its the 2nd time.

Comment: Actually, it is wrong do not let onSurfaceChanged method be called more than once, cause in case of width or height change it should be called.

Answer (score 1):

As **[harvey-slash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670775/harvey-slash)** suggested, you may not reinitialize everything when `onSurfaceChanged()` is called for the second time. The size of the surface has changed - so what? You may choose to set preview size that fits the new aspect ratio better, or to force the layout to fit the preview size that you have set before ([get](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLayoutParams()) the [`LayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html) and set negative margins).

One more tricky case is when the repeated call to `onSurfaceChanged()` is result of device orientation change. But even then, you can continue to reuse the camera.

Comment: I added a method which checks if width and height are changed and in that case i set a flag which decides to call setupSurfaceTexture or not.